# Interpretation of an undirected adjacency matrix

Tags: graph-theory, neural-networks, network

I am new and know not much about "graph theory" and "graph neural network". Assume, I have one incidence matrix $\mathbf{B}$ such as

| visitor | item1 | item2 | item3 | item4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 1 | 0 | 0 | 1 |
| B | 1 | 1 | 0 | 0 |
| C | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 |
| D | 0 | 0 | 1 | 1 |
| E | 1 | 0 | 1 | 1 |

Where 1 represents purchased and 0 represents no purchase. If I build an undirected adjacency matrix $\mathbf{A}$ for items such as $\mathbf{B}^T\mathbf{B}$ with the diagonal set to 0. The $\mathbf{A}$ is defined as

|  | item1 | item2 | item3 | item4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| $\textbf{item1}$ | 0 | 1 | 1 | 2 |
| $\textbf{item2}$ | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| $\textbf{item3}$ | 1 | 0 | 0 | 2 |
| $\textbf{item4}$ | 2 | 0 | 2 | 0 |

$\textbf{Question1:}$ Can I say that if a visitor purchased $\textbf{item3}$, a recommender system should recommend a visitor to purchase $\textbf{item4}$ and $\textbf{item1}$. The $\textbf{item4}$ will be the 1st recommendation because the weight (count) is 2 and $\textbf{item1}$ will be the 2nd recommendation because its weight is 1.

$\textbf{Question2:}$ Should I normalize item matrix $\mathbf{A}$ by row like following **OR**

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np 

B = np.array([
    [1,0,0,1],
    [1,1,0,0],
    [0,1,0,0],
    [0,0,1,1],
    [1,0,1,1]
])
A = np.transpose(B).dot(B)
np.fill_diagonal(A, 0)
print(A/A.sum(axis = 1).reshape(4,1))
```

```
[[0.         0.25       0.25       0.5       ]
 [1.         0.         0.         0.        ]
 [0.33333333 0.         0.         0.66666667]
 [0.5        0.         0.5        0.        ]]
```

$\tilde{\mathbf{A}} = \mathbf{D}^{-1/2}\mathbf{A}\mathbf{D}^{-1/2}$, where $\mathbf{D}$ is a degree matrix. The $\tilde{\mathbf{A}}$ is

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np 
from scipy.linalg import sqrtm, inv

B = np.array([
    [1,0,0,1],
    [1,1,0,0],
    [0,1,0,0],
    [0,0,1,1],
    [1,0,1,1]
])
A = np.transpose(B).dot(B)
diag = np.diagonal(A)
zero = np.zeros((4,4))
np.fill_diagonal(zero, diag)
dm = zero.copy() # degree matrix
D = inv(sqrtm(dm)) # D^(-1/2)
out = D.dot(A).dot(D)
np.fill_diagonal(out, 0)
print(out)
```

```
[[0.         0.40824829 0.40824829 0.66666667]
 [0.40824829 0.         0.         0.        ]
 [0.40824829 0.         0.         0.81649658]
 [0.66666667 0.         0.81649658 0.        ]]
```

many thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you can definitely say from the numbers $1, 0, 0, 2$ you have in matrix $\mathbf A$ is that out of the five visitors you've collected data on, there was $1$ who purchased **item3** together with **item1**, and there were $2$ who purchased **item3** together with **item4**.

Interpreting that any further is more about common sense than it is about mathematics, and also depends a lot on the application: what do you plan to use this conclusion for?

For example, if the plan is "if a customer purchases **item3**, I will use this data to recommend **item4** as well" then using matrix $\mathbf A$ is a mistake for the following reason. Imagine a data set in which **item1** is batteries, and **item2**, **item3**, **item4** are various battery-powered items: an emergency radio, a flashlight, and a calculator. Almost everyone who buys one of these items buys batteries for it as well. Then:

- It would be really useful to tell people buying the flashlight that lots of people like them bought the emergency radio (and not a lot bought the calculator).
- However, matrix $\mathbf A$ will begin by recommending batteries, because *everyone* who bought the flashlight bought batteries as well. This is still a useful reminder, but much less useful.
- Now imagine that the main thing your store sells is chocolate candy, and the electronics is only a side venture. All of the customers buying the flashlight have bought candy multiple times, and so matrix $\mathbf A$ will recommend candy to them on those grounds alone. This is now completely useless!

In such a scenario, you might want to normalize the columns of $\mathbf B$ first (say, so that each column adds up to $1$). Then $\mathbf B^{\mathsf T}\mathbf B$ will make more specific recommendations: if **item1** often gets purchased with **item2** and **item3**, but **item2** gets purchased a lot for other reasons as well, while **item3** almost always is only bought with **item1**, then **item3** will be a better recommendation.

On the other hand, if your goal is prediction, and not recommendation, then your original solution is the right choice. It *is* accurate that more people who buy flashlights will buy batteries than emergency radios, and it *is* accurate that they will all buy candy as well (in the example above).

Comment: thank you very much for your quick response. The goal of using A matrix is to find recommendation items. Two more questions:  (1) Why should I normalize matrix B not A? Why is normalized by "column" not by row? many thanks

Comment: We normalize the columns of $B$ so that an item that's bought by lots of people has smaller values and contributes to the entries of $B^{\mathsf T}B$ less; the logic is that if lots of people buy candy in general, then it's less noteworthy to see that lots of people who buy flashlights also buy candy.

Comment: Asking "why not normalize matrix A" and "why not normalize by row" is asking the wrong questions. We came up with a reason to normalize the columns of $B$. Until you come up with reasons to want to normalize anything else, you shouldn't.

Comment: many thanks for your quick response.